# Determine angles needed for fireworks

Tags: trigonometry

So I am unsure of where to ask this question but I was hoping that the people here might be able to help. I was thinking this might be a good spot because I ***think*** with the information I have it is possible to get the information I want using trig. I have not done a lot of trig and what little I have done was over a decade ago so I have no real working memory of it so please treat me as the novice I am.

Ok so here is the question in word problem form :)

I am wanting to shoot fireworks off and have the explosion offset across the sky so that I can spell words. Here are the things I know that I think would be useful: I know that the firework will fire at 117.5 ft/s, I know that if fired at 75 degree angle it will reach a height of 200 ft at a distance of around 125 ft away prior to explosion, I know that size of the burst will be 90 ft diameter. I am wanting to overlap the bursts to spell words think of trying to spell words with a bingo dauber. The words I am trying to spell are "Will you marry me?" I would do each word as a separate set of fireworks. So I am wanting to take that information and work backwards to figure out how far to spread the launch tubes and at what angles to get the desired effect.

A lot of the information I have about the explosion come from this site.
http://www.pyroinnovations.com/display-fireworks-facts.html

I understand if this is not something you can help with. I am just unsure of where to go for help on this. If there is any extra information you need I did not provide let me know and I will attempt to add that information.

Comment: Um, that sounds creative but also crazy ambitious. You're going to need to burn through _a lot_ of fireworks on tests to make sure how well you can aim simultaneous bursts in practice. It's probably more cost-effective to enlist the service of a professional pyrotechnician who knows the capabilities of his launching apparatus already.

Comment: The size of the burst looks large compared to the height reached, do you think there will be room enough to form letters ?

Comment: I have reached out to pyrotechnicians in the area and they are not willing to try. Also I am unconcerned with the cost of practice as I have a very large stockpile of these since I run a fireworks stand.

Comment: I have the whole sky for room. I have a giant pasture I can use for a shooting ground so i can space apart as far as several hundred feet. I plan on using electronic ignition so they will all light at the same time.

Comment: these are standard artillery shells you would purchase from a fireworks stand so you can think of that, if you have seen those, for an idea on size

Comment: To adjust the horizontal poisition, you can move the mortar on the ground. To adjust the vertical position, you can change the angle (and compensate for horizontal position simultaneously). You need to know the relation between angle and height. Due to aerodynamic effects, this might be difficult to model otherwise than by experimentation.

Comment: Could we assume no wind to get a baseline and therefore have a good starting point for experimentation?

Comment: The thing to be checked is if the trajectory follows a standard parabolic trajectory, or if drag enters into play. (With no wind.)

Comment: How would I find that out? Also the forum wants me move this to chat but i  dont have the rep to chat :(

Comment: Doesn't answer your math question, but can you rig up letters on poles using fountains/wheels, or float them from balloons? I'm with Henning and Yves: The parameters you specify (90 foot burst 200 feet off the ground) don't give you nearly enough resolution to spell words, and the irregularities of manufactured fireworks even in calm air seem unlikely to be precise enough to spell a marriage proposal legibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the intial speed $v_0$ and direction $\theta$ wrt the ground, the motion equations are (ignoring drag)

$$\begin{cases}x=&v_0\cos\theta\ t,\\y=&v_0\sin\theta\ t-\dfrac{gt^2}2\end{cases}$$ where $t$ is the flight time, which is (presumably) constant for a given shell type.

This equation simply describes a circle with radius $v_0\,t$ and its center  $\dfrac{gt^2}2$ feet below the ground.

On the picture, the ground is the thick double line, and the dashed line below represents the $\dfrac{gt^2}2$ term. By drawing a segment of constant length $v_0\,t$ (in red) from the points to be reached and intersecting the dashed line, you obtain the aiming directions $\theta$. The required horizontal offsets are given by the terms $v_0\cos\theta\ t$, i.e. the horizontal projections of the red segments.

[image]

---

An interesting experiment to be made is to fire several shells with varying angle and check if they explode along an imaginary circle in the sky.

Comment: So I understand enough of what you said to think this is going to being helpful in finding what i want. However I dont understand enough of it to work out the answer...so time to teach myself trig via google.

Comment: It will likely be a while before I will have time to figure out these equations in relation to my problem and then apply them in the field. Once I do have time I will come back and post results. Until then or until someone post something that feels better I am going to mark this answered. Good enough for a theory at least :)

Comment: @RealLifeMath: IMO what really matters to you is to be able to predict the horizontal and vertical offsets as a function of the angle.

Comment: Thank you I will focus on that.